# Java eclipse compiler is stuck with an old process. how to fix it?

Tags: java, eclipse, console

I am using Eclipse neon with Java 8. I am very basic so far with the programming stuff but my problem i think is not related to the programin but the eclipse itself.

I have some projects with basic code but when i try to run something as basic  as hello world the console does not do anything. the weird part is that when i open another project with a more complex code, the console shows the data.

Now, this is the weirdest thing. I close all projects and i keep the one that is "working" I comment the everything except the first line and i modify this line from "hi, enter your name" to only "hi" when i run the program, it shows all the last state of the program.

I do not know if my explanation is clear or not but i have tried to find is java director is ok and the source in java built path from the project properties but it looks very weird.

**Edit**
I have seen that when i run the program with the green play icon, does not save the change and run a previous version of the code. If i save manually and the compile, it works. But how do i fix this saving problem?

Comment: Can you show your code?

Comment: There is a good chance that the real problem is a bug in your "hello world" program.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might only need to make the appropriate selections on the Launching preference page. If you're using an external tool like Ant or Maven, this may not handle all of the possibilities.

[image: Appropriate selections on the Launching preference page]

Comment: Thanks. I wil take this into consideration for the next similar problem

Answer (score 0):

Well, i have fixed it, maybe in not the proper way but i deleted the .metadata folder in the workspace folder and it worked

Im not sure exactly the root cause of this problem, but as a beginner i would like to know what are the main downsides of this solution.

I noticed that the perspective is reset, but i dont know what else was reset besides this

Thanks

Comment: Information on which projects are in the workspace, and workspace-wide preferences were in there.